# How to print dynamic string in PDF header using onEndPage method

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I have multiple tables in my pdf document when printing one of the tables in pdf I need the name of the table to be printed in the header section in all the pages that the table is printed. Also, the header value needs to be changed according to the table name.

I have tried set new table name for the header for each table, however only last table name is printed for all pages.

sample code

PdfGenerator.class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        try {
            String pdfFilePath = "C:\\Users\\ychitela\\Desktop\\demo\\NewPdf.pdf";
            File file = new File(pdfFilePath);
            FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 36, 36, 55, 25);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileout);
            ReportHeader event = new ReportHeader();
            writer.setPageEvent(event);
            writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);
            document.open();
            document.addAuthor("Me");
            document.addTitle("Table Report");

            Font font = FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", 12, BaseColor.BLACK);
            document.add(new Paragraph("Intro Page"));
            document.newPage();
            Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph("Table \n\n"), 0);
            chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
            chapter.add(new Paragraph("   "));
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

                float[] columnWidths = { 1f, 1f };
                // create PDF table with the given widths
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
                table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table.setWidthPercentage(30.0f);
                Section subsection = chapter.addSection(new Paragraph("Table "+i+" \n\n"), 0);
                event.setTableName("Table header" + i);
                writer.setPageEvent(event);
                table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 1", font)));
                table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 2", font)));
                table.setHeaderRows(1);
                for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello" + j, font)));
                    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("World" + j, font)));
                }
                subsection.add(table);
                subsection.newPage();

            }
            document.add(chapter);
            document.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Header.class

```
public class ReportHeader extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    private String tableName;

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);

        try {
            BaseColor basecolour = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
            Font fontboldHead = FontFactory.getFont("TIMES_ROMAN", 8, basecolour);

            table2.setTotalWidth(300);
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(tableName, fontboldHead));
            cell2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
            table2.addCell(cell2);
            table2.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), 580, writer.getDirectContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"because onEndPage method is called only after the whole document is closed."* - no it isn't. But your code draws the table at `document.left(), document.bottom()` anyways,  i.e. at the bottom of the page, just outside the visible area. So what you see as *header* in your output is not generated by that code...

Comment: Hi, can you show what you are trying to achieve? Textual description does not seem to describe all the details

Comment: @AlexeySubach here is sample document [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/77atq3uzxhfvxfp/Pdf%20Example.docx?dl=0) . My pdf prints multiple tables and in each page at the footer or in the header the name of the table in that page should be printed.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce that the name of the last table would be printed on all pages - that actually is impossible, if there are many tables on many pages, the first tables have long ago been written to the output before the name of the last table is set to a page event instance, so that name cannot be on those first pages. But there is one issue in your code, the `PdfWriter.setPageEvent` "setter" is not really a "setter" but instead an "adder": it does not overwrite the previous page event listener but adds to it. To replace it, first `setPageEvent(null)` which clears the collection.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your comments, they were helpful. finally figured out where the issue is. I was using chapter and subsection in my actual code and looping and at the end of the loop, I'm adding the chapter to document. so that has been leading to only print only last table name. I'm updating the code with actual code to show the issue.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had assumed that your original `printTable` did add the table to the document, not merely a chapter. Ok, I assume you'd like a solution for the chapter-wise adding use case nonetheless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out yourself, the problem cause is

> I was using chapter and subsection in my actual code and looping and at the end of the loop, I'm adding the chapter to document. so that has been leading to only print only last table name.

To make the dynamic header as is work, you have to add the content more early; in particular you have to add the current contents of the chapter to the document each time you're adding a new table, i.e. each time the header will change.

You can do this by making use of the fact that `Chapter` implements `LargeElement`, i.e. you can add a `Chapter` instance to your document multiple times, and each time only everything new in the chapter since the last time is written to the document. To do so you have to set its `Complete` property to `false` at the start and back to `true` only before adding it the final time. Thus,

```
Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph("Table \n\n"), 0);
// prepare chapter to be set piecewise
chapter.setComplete(false);
chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
chapter.add(new Paragraph("   "));
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

    float[] columnWidths = { 1f, 1f };
    // create PDF table with the given widths
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.setWidthPercentage(30.0f);
    // add recent chapter additions
    document.add(chapter);
    Section subsection = chapter.addSection(new Paragraph("Table "+i+" \n\n"), 0);
    event.setTableName("Table header" + i);
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 1", font)));
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column 2", font)));
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hello" + j, font)));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("World" + j, font)));
    }
    subsection.add(table);
    subsection.newPage();

}
// prepare chapter to be completed
chapter.setComplete(true);
// final adding of chapter
document.add(chapter);
```

*([ChapterAndDynamicHeader](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/ChapterAndDynamicHeader.java#L117) test `testLikeYuvarajChitelaImproved`)*